# How do I stack matrices in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to insert a new row at the beginning of a matrix, but the result is inserting my row vector rotated:

```
a: (.7 .3; .1 .2)
b: (.5 .5)

b, a

0.5
0.5
0.7 0.3
0.1 0.2
```

Intended result:

```
0.5 0.5
0.7 0.3
0.1 0.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Makes no difference to the question, but you don’t need the parens when defining `b`. And omitting them might make it clearer that only `a` is a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(enlist b), a` gives the result you want. It helps to think of `a` as being made from nested lists, hence any new rows should be of this form as well.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can make `b` a matrix. [Join](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/join/) on matrices works the way you expect.

```
q)(1 2#b),a
0.5 0.5
0.7 0.3
0.1 0.2
```